# Run an .exe file from python code with path parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This throws file not found error, I guess because of the path argument. The path argument is needed for the clemb.exe, which is a batch runner for the stream. Even when I try to run it without the path arguments I get access dennied. I am currently running this from pycharm but I want to compile to a binary and ship to customer.

Any suggestions how to bypass the file not found error and the access denied issue?

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call([r'"C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Modeler\18.2\bin\clemb.exe -stream path\to\spss\modeller\stream\stream.str"'])
```

I am using Python 3.7

Comment: Are you sure the path to file is correct?

Comment: The ``subprocess`` APIs expect either *one string* of all arguments, or *one list* with a separate string for each argument. You have *one list* with *one string* of all arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Modeler\18.2\bin\clemb.exe', '-stream', r'path\to\spss\modeller\stream\stream.str'])
```

should be more clear and working.